# how do i write a string to a file without quote marks in scheme

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I'm trying to write a string to a file, but every time i do it has quotes around it.

I've tried

```lisp
(call-with-output-file file-path
  (lambda(output-port)(write "some text" output-port)))
```

and

```lisp
(let ((p (open-output-file file-path)))
      (write "some text" p)
      (close-output-port p))
```

but in both cases i expected `"some text"` but got `"\"some text\""`

I'm currently working in chicken-scheme but I don't think that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`write` is for serializing S-expressions to a file.  It is the opposite of `read`, which will read a serialized S-expression back into lists, symbols, strings and so on. That means `write` will output everything like it would occur in source code.

If you just want to output a string to a port, use `display`:

```
(call-with-output-file file-path
  (lambda(output-port)
    (display "some text" output-port)))
```

Or in CHICKEN, you can use `printf` or `fprintf`:

```
(call-with-output-file file-path
  (lambda(output-port)
    (fprintf output-port 
             "Printing as s-expression: ~S, as plain string: ~A"
             "some text"
             "some other test")))
```

This will print the following to the file:

```
Printing as s-expression: "some text", as plain string: some other text
```

Comment: thanks sjamaan - I got confused because the examples i had looked at were all using write (which seems like the right word to use to write to a file), and display seemed more intended for displaying to stdout / console. :)